# How we can sort table as custom ordered values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, sorting, logic

I want to sort the table based on custom values as below how we can write the logic for this from react side?

Order is

```
 no s, no c, ready, pub
```

as I want to sort the below data

```
const data = [
  {
    name: 'Harry',
    sort: 'no c',
  },
  {
    name: 'Don',
    sort: 'no s',
  },
  {
    name: 'Arc',
    sort: 'pub',
  },
  {
    name: 'Park',
    sort: 'ready',
  },
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an array of sort value in order that you want to sort data, then use filter function to get those value and push it to output array.

E.g.

```
let output = []
let order = ['no s','no c','pub','ready']
const data = [ { name: 'Harry', sort: 'no c', }, { name: 'Don', sort: 'no s', }, { name: 'Arc', sort: 'pub', }, { name: 'Park', sort: 'ready', }]

for(const o of order){
    output.push(...data.filter(d=>d.sort === o))
}

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = [
  { name: 'Harry', sort: 'no c', }, 
  { name: 'Don', sort: 'no s', }, 
  { name: 'Arc', sort: 'pub', }, 
  { name: 'Park', sort: 'ready', }, 
];

const order = [ 'no s', 'no c', 'ready', 'pub'];

const orderedArr = [];

order.forEach(element => {
  const item = arr.find((obj) => obj.sort === element);
  orderedArr.push(item);
});
```

Comment: it is working with only 4 values. What if I have 5 or more values in Data?

Comment: I'm not sure if I know what you mean with your question. It works as long as you provide an order for the elements, no matter the size.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This solution will sort an array of any length, so long as each element has a `sort` property.

```
data.sort((obj1, obj2) => {
  const order = ['no s', 'no c', 'ready', 'pub'];
  const getOrder = (obj) => order.findIndex(item => item === obj.sort);
  return getOrder(obj1) - getOrder(obj2);
}
```

EDIT:

I made the function cleaner by removing a bulky switch statement and an unnecessary variable.

Note that you need to guarantee each `sort` value is valid for this solution, otherwise the object will be placed at the front of the array. If you want different behavior for invalid values, you can handle that in the `getOrder` function if you want invalid ones at the end, or if you want to filter them out altogether, you can just tack on a `.filter(obj => order.includes(obj.sort))`.